# PHP & MySQL: Using a 'NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' on a table that truncates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm really stuck here I have this PHP script:

```
<?php


$databasehost = "localhost"; 
$databasename = ""; 
$databasetable = ""; 
$databaseusername=""; 
$databasepassword = ""; 
$fieldseparator = ","; 
$lineseparator = "\n";
$enclosedbyquote = '"';
$csvfile = "db-core/feed/csv/csv.csv";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
        $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$pdo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE `$databasetable`");

    $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." REPLACE INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
    FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
     TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)." 
    LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." 
    IGNORE 1 LINES");

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

?>
```

So as you can see that script is truncating my table with a CSV file. It replaces all the data currently in MySQL table.

This data is used to create a listing page that includes vehicles that are in stock, each row contains the data for one vehicle. This script is ran once a day to replace vehicles that are no longer in stock.

I now want to give each of my SQL rows it's own page, I've been told I will need to use a 'NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' attribute on an 'id' key.

However seen as my table truncates wont the ID removed each time my script is ran?

Could I add anything to my script to combat this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Yes. Truncating a table is the equivalent of `delete from table` and nuking all the records. But the auto_increment won't reset to 0 again. The last used auto_inc value is part of the table's metadata and is not affected by a truncate operation.</strike>

If you had records 0->100, truncated the table, then added new records, they would start at #101 and climb from there.

If you want the auto_increment value to be reset after the truncation, you'd have to do:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE foo; // delete all records
ALTER TABLE foo SET auto_increment=1; // reset auto-increment to 1
INSERT ...
```

So yep... turns out truncate does reset the auto_increment value. Definitely seems wrong, since it also apparently won't process any cascade deletes while truncating. Repopulating a truncated table that is used as a foreign key elsewhere will undoubtedly lead to incorrect record joinings.

Comment: I think you have this backwards. Truncate **will** reset the auto_increment where delete actions **will not**. [Delete Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94731a/1) showing keys that haven't reset. You can change the delete statement to a truncate and see they have reset.

Comment: Interesting... just tested it here.. that definitely seems wrong. an auto_inc value is never supposed to be recycled.

Comment: You made me think for a second and I had to test it first to confirm what I though (truncate resets).