# Giving MySQL rows unique ID's

Tags: php, mysql

so basically I'd like to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is my setup:

I have a listing page here: http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.php

So as you can see all of the vehicles on the page are listed from my SQL table using the following PHP:

```
<?php while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
      echo '
      <div class="makes ' . $row["Make"] . '">
        <div class="listing-container">
          <a href="carpage.php"><h3 class="model-listing-title clearfix">'.$row["Make"].' '.$row["Model"].' '.$row["Variant"].'</h3></a>
          <h3 class="price-listing">£'.number_format($row['Price']).'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-container-spec">
         <img data-original="'.(explode(',', $row["PictureRefs"])[0]).'" class="stock-img-finder lazy"/>
          <div class="ul-listing-container">
            <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
              <li class="diesel-svg list-svg">'.$row["FuelType"].'</li>
              <li class="saloon-svg list-svg">'.$row["Bodytype"].'</li>
              <li class="gear-svg list-svg">'.$row["Transmission"].'</li>
              <li class="color-svg list-svg">'.$row["Colour"].'</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul other-specs-ul h4-style">
            <li>Mileage: '.number_format($row["Mileage"]).'</li>
            <li>Engine size: '.$row["EngineSize"].'cc</li>
          </ul>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style checked-btn hover-listing-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> History checked 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style more-details-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> More details 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style test-drive-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="test-drive-glyph"></span> Test drive 
          </button>
          <h4 class="h4-style listing-photos-count"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> 5 More photos</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
          ';
      } ?>
```

All of the rows in my SQL table are looped with a WHILE loop.

So now I want to create a page dedicated to each one of the SQL rows/vehicles, so for example a user can click on one of the listed vehicles and it will take the user to a page with more details about that certain vehicle.

I have been told the best way to go about this is by giving each row a AUTO_INCREMENT id field.

I am a little confused about the whole processes though as my table is truncated daily by a CSV file so all data is wiped.

Does that mean if I had an AUTO_INCREMENT id field that it would wipe that also?

What is the process of adding an AUTO_INCREMENT id field to a table, I'm not completely sure what one is as there aren't many tutorials out there?

Comment: Didn't we do this a few days ago? Possible duplicate of [PHP & MySQL: Using a 'NOT NULL AUTO\_INCREMENT' on a table that truncates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223093/php-mysql-using-a-not-null-auto-increment-on-a-table-that-truncates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an auto-incrementing column to a table you do this -

```
ALTER TABLE `<table name>` ADD `<column name>` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Your auto-increment column will get wiped out, but it will start at the next available number. In other words, if the last id was 1099 the next record entered (whether or not the table was truncated) would be 1100. If you're using id's to generate pages you will want to provide some sort of redirect if that id no longer exists (for customers who may have bookmarked a certain vehicle).

If you truncate each day and a vehicle still exists from a previous day there is no way to guarantee that the vehicle would have the same id, which may be confusing to your customers. Why are you truncating? Do you have so many vehicles that you need to do this? Or perhaps you should consider adding a 'date sold' column and only show the vehicles which have not been sold. You can then purge those vehicles from the system on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks, made it very easy for me to understand.

I do have one question.

Can I set any of my columns to be auto_increment or does it need it's own column?

Comment: Btw couldn't I just use the registration of the vehicle as the ID? That would save me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Yes - vehicle registration would be a great way to go. That way you do not need an auto-incrementing column at all and each vehicle is uniquely identified.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all contents of your table and re-filling it every day with a new csv file is not a very good idea: It will cause the same row to have different ID's so you will not be able to bookmark a specific page of a specific car.

What I would do, is find a unique property or combination of properties and set that combination to be unique in the database.

Then you can use for example `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` when you add your daily cvs file to make sure that existing rows will get updated and only new rows will get added.

That way the ID's of existing rows will remain the same so you can always access a specific item with the same url.

Answer (score 0):

Jay Blanchard's [suggested code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26241868/1118357) will add the auto-increment field to your existing table. 
The [MySQL Truncate syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) explains that when you use truncate, it *will* reset the auto-increment counter:

> "(When fast truncation is used, it resets any AUTO_INCREMENT counter
>   to zero. From MySQL 5.0.13 on, the AUTO_INCREMENT counter is reset to
>   zero by TRUNCATE TABLE, regardless of whether there is a foreign key
>   constraint.)"

The second to last bullet on that page explains that this is one distinction between `TRUNCATE` and `DELETE`, as the latter doesn't *necessarily* reset the auto-increment:

> The table handler does not remember the last used AUTO_INCREMENT
>   value, but starts counting from the beginning [*using TRUNCATE, as opposed to DELETE*]. This is true even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence values.

[MySQL's Delete documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) gives details on how a `DELETE` command affects an auto-incrementing field (depending on the underlying engine):

> If you delete the row containing the maximum value for an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reused later for a BDB table, but
>   not for a MyISAM or InnoDB table. If you delete all rows in the table
>   with DELETE FROM tbl_name (without a WHERE clause) in autocommit mode,
>   the sequence starts over for all storage engines except InnoDB and
>   MyISAM.